# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am inserting values in lead_table but getting error as PRIMARY KEY must be unique.
Below is my code. Please guide me on how to resolve it as am new to android its difficult for me to find the exact error.

```
public void insertLead(ArrayList<String> data) {
        String insertString = "insert into lead_table " + " Values(";
        int row = 0;
        String inString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        inString = inString + "\"" + data.get(i) + "\",";
        }
        inString = inString.substring(0, inString.length() - 1);
        row = mDb.rawQuery("select * from lead_table;", null).getCount() + 1;
        insertString = insertString + row + "," + inString + ");";
        mDb.execSQL(insertString);
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your final insertString value with help of debuging??

Comment: @Andrain this is my final insertString="insert into lead_table  Values(7,"LEAD100024","2014-05-19","HGGG","4245589785", "SRFHJCVJHCJV","TAMIL NADU","THIRUVARUR","NEM12448","245556","Urban", "LOW","KG","BELAPUR","24722775","","249","TAB")";

Comment: How often did you run this method? Did you delete all entries from the table before rerunning the statement? When running the twice without deleting previous entries your PK already exists.

Comment: @Trinimon  No i will delete the row if its not updated for fifteen days or if its sent to server

Comment: How does your table  definition look like, and which records do you have _before_ inserting the new record? Please add to the question above ....

Comment: @Trinimon This is the code which i used to delete row          public boolean leadDelete(String tbl) {
        return mDb.delete(tbl, "( date < date('now','-15 day') ) AND (FLAG = 'TAB') ", null) > 0;
    }

Comment: please post your table creation definition.

Comment: @Andrain Plz check the create table def which I'm using.CREATE TABLE [lead_table] ([id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[lead_id] VARCHAR(20)  NULL,[date] DATE  NULL,[customer_name] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,[cust_mobile] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,[address] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,[State] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,[city] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,[NEM] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,[pincode] VARCHAR(20)  NULL,[addrstype] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,[type] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,[product] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,[branch] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,[value] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,[comments] VARCHAR(300)  NULL,[branchID] VARCHAR(10)  NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tries to compute a yet-unused ID value by counting the records in the table, but this does not guarantee that the resulting value is actually unused.
For example, if the table contains the three ID values `1`, `3`, and `4`, then the value computed by this code will be `4`.

Your PRIMARY KEY column already is defined as AUTOINCREMENT.
The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says:

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.

So you can just tell the database to create the ID for you, by using NULL instead of a number:

```java
    ...
    inString = inString.substring(0, inString.length() - 1);
    // no row variable
    insertString = insertString + "NULL" + "," + inString + ");";
    mDb.execSQL(insertString);
    ...
```

Comment: cl is right and if you don't pass any value as an id then database will make a default value for you to insert a row in database.@Ramesh